# how to hide the rows in table when value is something

Tags: php

In the Database table , if the  column "**two**"'s value is "**world**", than i am trying to hide that row.

```
<thead>
<tr>
<th>one</th>
<th>two</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <?php

        $hide='';

        if(!empty($orderrecords)) 
        {
            foreach($orderrecords as $k=>$v) 
            {
                ?>
                <tr value="<?php echo $hide;?>"
                <td><?php echo $orderrecords[$k]["tracking_id"]; ?></td>
                <td>
                <?php 
                    if ($row['two'] == "world") 
                    {
                        $hide .= 'style="display: none;"';
                    }

                    echo $orderrecords[$k]["world"]; 

                ?>
                </td>
            <tr>

<?php 
    $tabindex++;
    }
}
?>
</tbody>
```

please let me know if you need more information, i am using mysqli....

Comment: so wehre are you outputting the hide variable?

Comment: where is $row coming from? you need to probably just add <tr <?=$hide?>>

Comment: @herriekrekel please check updated question , i added as `<tr value="<?php echo $hide;?>"`

Comment: it's recommended to not render that rows in your html, because they can be visible if somebody change your html code, then i suggest you to filter your db to get rows that should be visible

Comment: You're using `$hide` in your `<tr>` but fill/define it afterwards.

Comment: @vickeycolors right 2 problems here the hide will never be filled with display none since you have the statement below the output, also don't put the styling inside a value attribute just put it directly in row like: <tr <?php echo $hide; ?> >

Comment: I support the opinion from @Farrokh .  Can you explain the benefit to your project from writing invisible rows to your html table / dom?  It seems to me that you should be filtering out these rows in your WHERE clause before they even make it to the resultset.

Comment: Calling `empty()` before your loop may be needless unless you are also checking for existence of the variable -- a foreach loop simply won't iterate an empty array.  Instead of accessing array data using `$orderrecords[$k]`, just use `$v`... that's what it is for.

Comment: @herriekrekel Thanks for help....

Comment: @kerbholz i will try as you suggested,  Thanks for help....

Comment: @mickmackusa  i will try as you suggested, Thanks for help....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You `style` attribute needs to be inside the `<tr>` tag :

```
foreach($orderrecords as $k => $v) 
{
    $hide = ''; // reset $hide variable to avoid to hide other rows
    if ($v['two'] == "world") 
    {
        $hide = 'style="display: none;"';
    }
    ?>
    <tr <?php echo $hide;?> >
        <td><?php echo $v["tracking_id"]; ?></td>
        <td>
        <?php 
            echo $v["world"]; 
        ?>
        </td>
    <tr>
```

Comment: sorry, that didt worked , here is code : https://pastebin.com/m9DFf4gj , please check once.....

Comment: @vickeycolors Where come from `$row`? does it `$v` instead of `$row`?

Comment: There is certainly a disconnect regarding `$row` with the OP's code.

Answer (score 1):

You are initialising $hide value too late. Also, you don't need to append it. Try the code below:

```
<?php
    $hide='';

    if(!empty($orderrecords)) 
    {
        foreach($orderrecords as $k=>$v) 
        {
            $hide = $row['two'] == "world" ?  ' style="display: none;"' : '';
            ?>
            <tr<?php echo $hide;?>>
            <td><?php echo $orderrecords[$k]["tracking_id"]; ?></td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $orderrecords[$k]["world"]; ?>
            </td>
        <tr>

       <?php 
           $tabindex++;
       }
   }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me.... as other user provided answer first , i accepted that.....

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to hide rows, I'd do the following:

```
<tr style="<?php if($row['two'] == "world") echo 'display:none;'; ?>">
```

You don't need the variable `$hide`.

Comment: Cleaner would be not to generate an empty style attribute when the condition is false.

Comment: `hidden` is not a valid value for `display`.  Be very careful about the advice you give.  We don't want to poison the minds of future researchers.

Comment: Thanks... lost in thoughts!